# Get home cell address in Excel

Tags: excel-formula

I need a function that adds a value from one constant cell with the left cell relative to the cell that homes the function:

```
=I7 + value in address((current row - 1) current column)
```

but I don't know what the function that gets the current cell address.

What function should I use? And how to use it?

the value in I7 is a date and the value on the left cell of the function will be a number, for example, the value in I7 is 13/04/2021 and the left of the cell function will be 5 so I expected a 18/04/2021

even if a date cant add with a number, at least I know the function

Comment: can you add more clarity ! like give a example with values and the result expected

Comment: @Ranga done, I already attach it to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there are two ways you can do this:

- Use $-sign to 'lock' references to either the row or column (if the value is always in a specific row/column), like this:

`=$B2+C$1`

[image]

- Or use OFFSET, where you can use any cell as a reference, and shift either an x amount of rows or columns (or both) to a different cell, relative to the reference cell:

`=$B4+OFFSET(C4,-3,0)`

[image]

Comment: Thank you for answering my problem, but what function returns a cell position(The position where you put the = sign, the current cell)

Comment: Do you mean =ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()) ? This formula in Cell A1 results in the text $A$1. I first tried =CELL("address"), but this returns the last-modified cell